# Database Maintenance Plan Update Statistics Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration, maintenance-plan

I get an error last night ,I get the following error message:

> Executing the query "UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[tables]  W..." failed
>   with the following error: "The multi-part identifier "tables.Id" could
>   not be bound.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query,
>   "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly,
>   or connection not established correctly.

Comment: Take a backup of the database, then run [`DBCC CHECKDB;`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064.aspx), see if the integrity of the database is still OK.

Comment: yes i did ,it 's ok